# Can I wash my oil pan with soap and water?

Tags: honda, oil, oil-pan

I took my oil pan off of my 96 Honda Accord 25th anniversary sedan, and I washed it with dish soap and water. I'm pretty sure I washed all the soap off. Should I worry?

Answer (score 2):

No, it should be ok. Doesn't hurt to give it another rinse though if you're worried. Just make sure the rim of the oil pan is clean and free of debris/ old gasket before installing the new gasket to ensure a proper seal.

Answer (score 1):

Mineral spirits (or jet fuel, kerosene, diesel, gasoline, basically anything that is a strong solvent and has a chemistry comparable to the one of motor oil) would've been a much better choice, but if you rinsed the soap away and then let the water dry out before putting everything back into place, then it's ok. Hope you cleaned the oil pickup too.